# Show that two distinct solutions of a normal first order linear differential equation cannot have a point of intersection.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

(Page 125 of file, page 106, problem 19 of the book - [Linear Analysis](https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToLinearAnalysis))

Hi friends - Could you please help me verify, if the arguments in my below attempted proof are correct?

> Q. Show that two **distinct solutions** of a normal first order linear differential equation cannot have a point of intersection.

*Proof.* My attempt.

Let $L=a_1(x)D+a_0(x)$ be a linear differential operator of the first order and let

$$Ly=h$$

be the given differential equation.

Suppose $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two distinct solutions of the differential equation. Then,

$$\begin{aligned}
Ly_1&=h&\\
Ly_2&=h&\\
\therefore Ly_1 - Ly_2&=0 & \\
\implies L(y_1-y_2)&=0 & (\text{since L is a linear operator})\\
\implies GL(y_1-y_2)&=G(0) & (\text{G is the inverse operator of L})\\
\implies y_1-y_2 &=G(0) & \\
\implies y_1(x)-y_2(x)&=G(0)(x) & \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \\
\implies y_1(x)&\neq y_2(x) & \forall x\in \mathbb{R} 
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.

1. How do you know $L$ is invertible? For instance, if $a_0(x)=0$, then $L$ is **not** invertible, for if $y(x)$ is a solution of $Ly=h$, then $y+C$ is a solution as well, for any constant $C$.
2. Even if we suppose that $L$ is invertible with inverse $G$, the inverse would be a *linear* operator, too, meaning that $G(0) = 0$, since this is how linear operators work. So, you actually proved that $Ly_1=Ly_2 \Rightarrow y_1 \color{red}{=} y_2$, which would indeed be the case, provided $L$ is invertible.
3. You haven't actually used the assumption that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are *distinct* solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity! As an aside from the above proof, wouldn't it be true, that subject to an initial condition $y(x_0)=k_0$, there is a unique solution $\implies$ $L$ is invertible? 

Let me see, what I can get out of assuming $y_1$ and $y_2$ are distinct.

Comment: @Quasar I believe existence & uniqueness depend on the properties of $a_1$ and $a_0$. If those are satisfied, the operator is indeed invertible; as I've shown in the answer, you need *at least* $a_0 \neq 0$. Note that $y_1 \neq y_2$ means $\exists x \, y_1(x) \neq y_2(x)$, while you are to prove that $\forall x \, y_1(x) \neq y_2(x)$, — note the difference.